# Composable FLinq expressions

Tags: linq-to-sql, f#

When doing linq-to-sql in c#, you could do something like this:

```
var data = context.MyTable.Where(x => x.Parameter > 10); 

var q1 = data.Take(10); 
var q2 = data.Take(3); 

q1.ToArray(); 
q2.ToArray();
```

This would generate 2 separate SQL queries, one with TOP 10, and the other with TOP 3. In playing around with Flinq, I see that:

```
let data = query <@ seq { for i in context.MyTable do if x.Parameter > 10 then yield i } @> 

data |> Seq.take 10 |> Seq.toList 
data |> Seq.take 3 |> Seq.toList
```

is not doing the same thing. Here it seems to do one full query, and then do the "take" calls on the client side. An alternative that I see used is:

```
let q1 = query <@ for i in context.MyTable do if x.Param > 10 then yield i } |> Seq.take 10 @> 
let q2 = query <@ for i in context.MyTable do if x.Param > 10 then yield i } |> Seq.take 3 @>
```

These 2 generate the SQL with the appropriate TOP N filter. My problem with this is that it doesn't seem composable.  I'm basically having to duplicate the "where" clause, and potentially would have to duplicate other other subqueries that I might want to run on a base query.  Is there a way to have F# give me something more composable?

(I originally [posted this question to hubfs](http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/thread/13838.aspx), where I have gotten a few answers, dealing with the fact that C# performs the query transformation "at the end", i.e. when the data is needed, where F# is doing that transformation eagerly.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do this in F#, you'll need to use slightly different approach. Instead of composing the query using method calls (and defered execution), you'll need to construct the quoted F# code. If you simply need to parameterize the code by some numeric argument, you can write a function that runs the query:

```
let takeData count = 
  <@ seq { for i in context.MyTable do 
             if x.Parameter > 10 then 
               yield i }
     |> Seq.take count @> |> query
```

This works only in simple cases, because the parameter can be only a number. However, you can also compose F# quotations in a way that allows you to add other operations to a core query.

For example, let's say that you want to append either `Seq.take` or `Seq.sortBy` to the core part of the query. This can be done using so called *splicing operator*. Inside quotations (code within `<@ .. @>`) you can use a special operato `%` that allows you to *splice* another quotation into the one you're building:

```
let createQuery op = 
  <@ seq { for i in context.MyTable do 
             if x.Parameter > 10 then 
               yield i }
     |> %op @> |> query
```

Here, the `op` parameter is of type `Expr<seq<MyTableRow> -> 'a>`. You can call the `createQuery` function with some quotation as an argument and it will append the argument after the core query. For example:

```
createQuery <@ Seq.take 10 @>
createQuery <@ Seq.sortBy (fun x -> x.Parameter) @>
```

This is actually much more powerful than what C# allows you to do. I wrote two articles about this some time ago:

- [Composing LINQ queries at runtime in F#](http://tomasp.net/articles/dynamic-flinq.aspx) shows some F# examples - unfortunately, it uses outdated syntax, so it won't directly work, but it should demonstrate the ideas. In older versions F#, you could use `_` in the quotation which automatically created a function that took quotation (to be spliced in place of `_` as an argument). This would have to be rewritten using (you also don't need funny Unicode characters anymore :-)):

  ```
  (fun x -> <@ .. %x .. @>)
  ```
- [Composing LINQ queries at runtime in C#](http://tomasp.net/articles/dynamic-linq-queries.aspx) shows how to provide some additional features that are not directly available in C# (using some tricks)